# Is there a way to set permissions so that a content editor part can be edited but not removed from the page?

Tags: 2010, web-part, permissions, publishing-site

I have a client scenario in which users need to be able to edit content within a content editor web part placed on a page via site template, but they need to be prevented from removing the web part from the page.

Any suggestions?  If there isn't a good way to achieve this with the CEWB, then is there a third-party web part that might work better for me?

Comment: Use a wiki page?

Comment: Well, I don't think a Wiki page is the right answer for this particular scenario, but I _was_ thinking of putting a rich text area in a page layout.  Users would have to have edit permissions to change it, but they wouldn't be able to remove it from the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a webpart in the pagelayout on a page. result -> it can;t be removed, but content can be edited. Another option would be to add a richfield editor as a webcontrol in the page layout.